# Bind external script events to html in components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call an external script

In `public/index.html`

```
<script src="https://embed.selly.gg"></script>
```

An event is suppose to be called when I click on a button with a specific data tag.

In `components/shop/ShopItem.js`

```
<button className={classes.button} data-selly-product={product.id}>
    Buy
</button>
```

But nothing happens.

How do I bind the events from embed.selly.gg to the component html?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://embed.selly.gg";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Well, that worked, IF i did it in the ShopItem component, but the shopItem component iterates a lot of times, so there would be multiple script tags. So I need to do this in either App.js or Shop.js will shopItem is imported. How?

Answer (score 0):

What if you simple ping the parent on mount with a function and put 
@piyush-zalani 's script registration method there with a condition. If the script has been loaded, do not load again.

**Shopitem.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
  const { onMount } = this.props;
  onMount('https://embed.selly.gg');
}
```

**Shop.js**

```
...
state = {}

handleCreateScriptTag = src => {
  const { loadedScripts } = this.state;
  if (loadedScripts && loadedScripts.indexOf(src) > -1) return;

  const script = document.createElement("script");

  script.src = src;
  script.async = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    loadedScripts: [...prevState.loadedScript, src]
  }))
}

render() {
  return (
    <ShopItem onMount={this.handleCreateScriptTag} />
  )
}
```

Comment: How do I check if it's in scope?

Comment: Or simply store in parent's state if a script is already loaded. I modified my code.

Comment: I tried to fix. Now I initialized the state plus checked if loadedScripts if existing before checking indexOf...