# Bind external script click event to a component, but only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Shop Component which has another Component called ShopItem. There's about a dozen ShopItems that's rendered, and fetch from an API call.

```
//Shop
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id='shop' className={classes.shopContainer}>
                <Container className={classes.container}>
                    <div className={classes.root}>
                        <SwipeableViews index={this.state.value} onChangeIndex={this.onChange}>
                            {
                            this.props.productGroups.map((productGroup) => {
                                if (productGroup.product_ids.length > 0) {
                                    return (
                                        <TabContainer key={productGroup.id}>
                                            <div className={classes.packages}>
                                                {
                                                this.props.products.map((product, index) => {
                                                    if (productGroup.product_ids.includes(product.id)) {
                                                        return (
                                                            <ShopItem
                                                                index={index}
                                                                maxProducts={this.props.products.length}
                                                                key={product.id}
                                                                product={product}
                                                                onBuyClick={this.onBuyClick}
                                                                buyingProduct={this.state.buyingProduct}
                                                            />
                                                        );
                                                    }
                                                })}
                                            </div>
                                        </TabContainer>
                                    );
                                }
                            })}
                        </SwipeableViews>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
// ShopItem 
render() {
    const { classes, product } = this.props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.package}>
                <h3 className={classes.packageTitle}>{product.title}</h3>

                <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                <div className={classes.packageDescription}>
                    <p>{product.description.split('\n')[0]}</p>
                </div>
                <button className={classes.button} data-selly-product={product.id}>
                    Buy
                </button>   
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );  
}
```

I'd like to embed [this script](https://selly.gg/help/article/embed-a-product-on-a-website) so when I click on a button with `data-selly-product` attribute, the script runs it's click event.

My attempt was to attach this to either App, Shop, or even ShopItem, and none of the methods work except for ShopItem, but using that method, I get a script loaded into the document for every item.

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://embed.selly.gg";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you use htmlWebpackPlugin, you can add the script directly on the template html file.

Comment: @johnnypeter not using webpack, using react starter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind external script events to html in components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252640/bind-external-script-events-to-html-in-components)

Answer (score 0):

As per the instructions here https://selly.gg/help/article/embed-a-product-on-a-website, you should put `<script src="https://embed.selly.gg"></script>` before the end of `</head>` in your `public/index.html` file.

However, this would not load the script dynamically in the pages where you only have your products on. But as a SPA, this will guarantee that the script is loaded once unless you fully reloaded your website.

Comment: I tried this and the events do not bind to the react elements.